# Checking for Selection in Geoprocessing Widget Web AppBuilder

Tags: geoprocessing-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I published a gp tool and used the out-of-box geoprocessing widget.

When a user selects a layer to be processed, the gp process will call the FeatureService(FS) x number of times to get all the features in the layer. There is about 1 million features in the FS. This takes around 2 mins. Very annoying for a user. This is of course only happens when a user forgets to make a selection. Which is the main issue here.

Things I've tried.

- In my GP script I stop if there is over 10,000 features, used the getCount() method. Still requests all the features before it submits the job.
- On the client side I tried to tried to stop it my not sending the job if there is more than 10,000 features. Still to late in the step. It still calls like 20 - 30 xhr in the network window. In the code below I added the  if (inputValues.Layers.features.length < 10000)  statement.

  executeGP: function(){
  this._clearLastResult();
  html.addClass(this.exeNode, 'jimu-state-disabled');
  this._getInputParamValues().then(lang.hitch(this, function(inputValues){
  this._showLoading();

  ```
    esriRequest({
      url: this.config.taskUrl,
      content: {
        f: 'json'
      },
      handleAs : "json",
      callbackParamName:'callback'
    }).then(lang.hitch(this, function() {
      if(this.config.isSynchronous){
        this.gp.execute(inputValues);
        this.infoTextNode.innerHTML = this.nls.executing;
      }else{
        if (inputValues.Layers.features.length < 10000) {
          this.gp.submitJob(inputValues);
          console.log("Good")
          this.tab.selectTab(this.nls.output);
        } else {
          alert("Please make a Selection")
          html.removeClass(this.exeNode, 'jimu-state-disabled');
        }
      }

    }), lang.hitch(this, function() {
      html.removeClass(this.exeNode, 'jimu-state-disabled');
    }));
  }), lang.hitch(this, function() {
    html.removeClass(this.exeNode, 'jimu-state-disabled');
  }))f
  ```

  }

I need to enable the run button only when there is a selection made.

How do I got about doing this?

I know I didn't give all the code.

I found this in the widget.js

```
    useSelectionAsInput: function(featureSet, layer) {
  array.forEach(this.inputNodes, function(node){
    if (node.param.dataType === 'GPFeatureRecordSetLayer' &&
        node.param.defaultValue &&
        utils.getTypeByGeometryType(node.param.defaultValue.geometryType) ===
        featureSet.geometryType) {
      node.inputEditor.setFeatureSet(featureSet, layer);
    }
  }, this);

  this.tab.selectTab(this.nls.input);
}
```

Not sure how this plays with the executeGP function. This happens in WAB 2.13. When I'm on WAB 2.16 it stops the call immediately not sure how, but I need this to work on 2.13

The image below shows that it's making all these requests.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of data, where I suppose it is a hosted feature layer, you can use getSelectedFeatures() method on a feature layer(s). It will return you an array of the selected features for a particular layer. This way you can check if anything is actually selected or not and proceed further.